# MySQL select count different data from same tables Best approach

Tags: mysql, database

i am trying to get count of values in same table but different where clause. 
Which one is best approach for that

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE post_id = 123 AND action_type IN(1,3,7,9,10)) as 'a',
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE post_id = 123 AND action_type IN(2,7,8,18)) as 'b'
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE post_id = 123 AND action_type IN(1,3,7,9,10)
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE post_id = 123 AND action_type IN(2,7,8,18)
```

Note: Table contains millions of values

Comment: it is a bit unclear to me *why* you are counting with the condition `WHERE id = 123` - if your id-field is unique, the counting-result can only ever be one or zero. if it is not unique, then it is at least confusingly named.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann that is another column.. i edit the question

Comment: ah. now with a foreign key, that makes a lot more sense, thank you for the clarification

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* so as to get data in one query without subqueries:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN action_type IN(1,3,7,9,10) THEN id END) AS count_1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN action_type IN(2,7,8,18) THEN id END) AS count_2
FROM table 
WHERE id = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

1st because it will execute only one time and Optimized way